# Understanding the variance of a value vector (RL Theory)

Tags: variance, reinforcement-learning

I am self studying "Reinforcement Learning:
Theory and Algorithms" by (Agarwal et al. 2022) and would like some help understanding the variance of a value vector.

They write that for $V \in \mathbb{R}^{|S|}$ we define the vector $Var_P(V) \in \mathbb{R}^{|S|\times |A|}$ as
$ Var_P(V)(s,a) = Var_{P(\cdot | s,a)}(V)$ where $s' \sim P(\cdot | s,a)$ is the probability distribution of the next state $s'$.

I do not understand what to make of $ Var_P(V)(s,a) = Var_{P(\cdot | s,a)}(V)$- how can we interpret the variance of a vector to be a scalar? I believe it must be a scalar since we have $Var_P(V) \in \mathbb{R}^{|S|\times |A|}$.